# How to switch off creation of session for Jspx globally?

Tags: session, jspx

Its annoying to put `jsp:directive.page session="false"` in each jspx page. So is there any opportunity to switch this session create off in one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, there's no 'global-session-place-holder-for jsp'. you need to declare it per jspx page.